# Not working prevent scrolling parent with mousewheel js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, mousewheel

I tried to prevent parent scrolling with mousewheel in Latest Google Chrome but it doesn't work. So I need some explanation with the code.

```
$(function() {


var toolbox = $('#68').find('.medium-folder-body'),

//The medium-folder-body height - 500px here
height = toolbox.height(),

//scrollHeight 693px (I got the height but don't understand what is that for)
//what is .get(0) ?
scrollHeight = toolbox.get(0).scrollHeight;

toolbox.bind('mousewheel', function(e, d) {

//This is js question which I don't understand often - What is 'this'?
//Second question. What is d?
    if((this.scrollTop === (scrollHeight - height) && d < 0) || (this.scrollTop === 0 && d > 0)) {
      alert(this.scrollTop);
    }
  });

});
```

The html is quite messy. I make it simple here

```
<div class="folder">
   <div class="header"></div>
   <div class="medium-folder-body">
     <ul class="photo-lists></ul>
   </div>
   <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

folder-body css `height:500px overflow-y:scroll`

Comment: @ExplosionPills Html added the html quite messy, I make it simple

Comment: @ExplosionPills  Forgot to mention, scrolling to top working, but reached bottom not working means will scroll the parent

Comment: @ExplosionPills What does it mean?   http://jsbin.com/ixura3 It actually prevented. Just mine not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not including the additional plugin that handles the mousewheel scroll direction data:

```
<script src="https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/raw/master/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/ZQgfr/

Comment: I did 
    <script src="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/lib/mousewheel/mousewheel.js'?>" type="text/javascript">
    </script>

Comment: @vzhen are you sure it's being included (and at the right time)?  Do you have a link to your website?

Comment: No, it is on localhost and yes, definitely in the right time. And funny here, IT WORKS NOW.  I have no idea why, maybe typo or what? LOL  thanks for your time any way.